# BMW i3 Range-Extended REx exhaust pipe? But where?

Tags: bmw, exhaust, automotive-design, front-pipe

I have a similar puzzle regarding:

> the BMW i3 Range-Extended REx exhaust pipe, where is it?

See also, https://www.mybmwi3.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=197

BMW i3 is an electric car, so the exterior does not seem to show any exhaust pipe. However, it has also 647-cc two-cylinder gas-powered REX onboard generator. So there should be an exhaust pipe somewhere.

If the location of pipes evolves from years to years, I am interested in knowing the old version like BMW i3 2014. Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's hidden under the rear of the car:

[image]

http://bmwi3.blogspot.com/2013/09/i3-range-extender-closer-look.html